# Uses for never-ending loops

Tags: loops, infinite-loop

What are some uses of never-ending loops? They are usually bad news in programming, but is there ever a time when you want a loop to never end?

Comment: When asking for user's input until some input arrives, e.g. "quit": `while True: cmd = input(); if cmd == "quit": break`

Comment: Windows application is an example of endless loop when messages are being received and processed in so called *winproc*. When message to close is being received (WM_QUIT), the loop is exited and program is terminated.

Comment: Your car is an infinite loop. Turn the key and the computer computer fuel, spark advance, and idle speed forever, looping infinitely. A video game is an infinite loop. An ATM is an infinite loop. A web server is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite loops are only bad news when they are not intended or their use has unintended consequences. If you use them with intent there is no difference from any other classification of loop you might consider. However you will still end up breaking things despite intentional use. It is common to use this form when you want to access the iterator or index component after the loop has been terminated, for example:

```c
index = 0;
result = null;
for (;;)
    result = foo(index);
    if (bar(result))
        break;
    index += result;
use(index, result);
```

Note that mutating data outside of the loop's scope may be very undesirable depending on the context, so whether or not this is a good use case really depends on the context. For another similar example, an actual iterator may be the object desired outside of the loop, but initializing it within the loop header would not allow access outside of the loop. An infinite loop would resolve this problem.

```c
for (foo.iterator(); foo.hasNext(); ) {
    use(foo.next());
}
keep_using(foo.next());  // throws an error
```

Additionally, infinite loops can in some cases improve readability, especially if there are many break conditions but they might not all derive from mutually exclusive units. For example, imagine we have the following:

```c
for (;;) {
    if (condition1)
        break;
    else if (condition2)
        do_stuff();
    else if (condition3)
        break;
    else
        do_something();
}
```

This can be rewritten using the three components of a loop as:

```c
for (condition = true; condition; iteration) {
    if (condition1 || condition3)
        condition = false;
    else if (condition2)
        do_stuff();
    else
        do_something();
}
```

However if we introduce a small amount of change (at least in terms of characters on the screen) to the original code:

```c
for (;;) {
    if (condition1);
        break;

    if (condition2);
        do_stuff();

    if (condition3);
        break;
    else
        do_something();
}
```

The rewrite becomes this thing that requires us to lug around this extra variable:

```c
for (condition = true; condition; iteration) {
    if (condition1)
        condition = false;

    if (condition2) {
        do_stuff();
        condition = true;
    }

    if (condition3)
        condition = false;
    else {
        do_something();
        condition = true;
    }
}
```

This can quickly become difficult to read and maintain as the loop body, and especially the complexity grows, for example if `condition` were actually many different conditions such as `a || b || c < d || (e > f) && (a > f)`; or, the loop contained several nested loops. Though you might apply the same logic to other the original changed version.

Another readability related example involves verbose initialization, though admittedly not a very good use case:

```c
for (more_long = some_ridiculously_long.initialization_statement.longer_than.Long_Long_Mans_Sakeru_gummy();
    more_long < lots_of && more_long < break_conditions
    maybe_even_an_update_that_hangs_at_ninety_nine_percent) {
    ...
}
```